# How to customize the presentation of faces messages

Tags: validation, jsf-2

I would like to customize the presentation of faces messages.

For this,

```
<h:inputText id="name" required="true" />
```

when validation is failed, then it will be shown in a

```
<h:message for="name" />
```

However, I would like to customize the presentation call JS as follows:

```
<div class="notification"></div>
function showNotification(msg){
$(".notification").html(msg);
$(".notification").fadeIn(1000, function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".notification").fadeOut(1000);
    }, 5000);
});
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) to get the messages in the view, if necessary the ones for a specific client ID. You can iterate over them in a [`ui:repeat`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html). Each item is a [`FacesMessage`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) which has several getters. You can display any HTML in the message unescaped by using `<h:outputText escape="false">`.

So, in a nutshell:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList('form:name')}" var="message">
    <div><h:outputText value="#{message.summary}" escape="false" /></div>
</ui:repeat>
```

*(in the above example, I assume that your form has `id="form"`)*

Or, if that HTML help link is *actually* not part of the message, then so:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{facesContext.messageList('form:name')}" var="message">
    <div>#{message.summary} <a href="help.xhtml">help</a></div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Just let JSF print `<script>showNotification('#{message.summary}')</script>`, provided that your message doesn't contain characters which could break JS code such as newlines.